# Can i use doument.cookie to edit a cookie created with request.set_cookie in django project?

Tags: javascript, django, cookies

I am working on a Django project. Basically a simple game that uses x and y cordinates to determine the pos
of the player on the map using js.

So i figured that using cookies to "save" the progress of the player would be a simple way for what i need. Since i need to get these parameters from  javascript file i was wondering if i could edit them directly from the file without the need of using a json to pass them to the views.py in order to check if the cookie is empty or has data when the user selects either load game or start a new one. I prefer doing it this way if possible to be able to maintain cookies without expiring thanks to django sessions engine since i haven't found a way to pass the data directly between the views.py and the .js files. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Are you looking to store data on the client? The cookie would be more for identifying the client so you know what data stored on the server side to use. If you want to save data on the client-side and don't care if the user edits it, I'd just use `localStorage`.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out hahaha, this is a project for college before it was changed to be a game, it was pretty much just a page with utilities for freshman, but it was sorta scrapped along the way and changed into a game by the professor (since there were already too many similar projects). The thing is it needs to use cookies so i can't change it to use localStorage but thanks for the suggestion.